# A pair of minus signs ( =- - ) at the beginning of a formula

Tags: excel

I stumbled upon this formula:

```
=--ISNUMBER(IFERROR(SEARCH($B$3,E3,1),""))
```

What does the `=--` at the beginning of the formula mean?

I can't seem to find the answer.

Comment: I can't imagine why anyone would do this, but -- means to negate a negative.  So --1 would be positive 1.  The = simply envokes the formula

Comment: fwiw, that formula does not use it properly. The [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) is totally unnecessary and possibly detrimental. The [SEARCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SEARCH-function-F79EF0B8-0991-4FC1-93B0-627F019A69E3) will return a number or an error and the [ISNUMBER function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/is-functions-490afee4-fd91-4839-89d4-1257a21b4e25) can handle that directly. `=--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$3,E3,1))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ISNUMBER() function returns a Boolean value of `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Often the `--` sequence is referred to as a double unary operator. It's not really,as Excel has no such operator, but it amounts to the same thing.

What it does is coerces the Boolean value to its numeric equivalent. In Excel worksheet formulas this means either `1` or `0`.

The `--` sequence is really just two minus signs back to back. Here is how it works. If the Boolean result of ISNUMBER() is TRUE, the first negative of that is the value `-1`. The second negative turns this into `+1`. Of course if the Boolean had been zero, well negative of that is zero and negative of that again is still zero.

The Boolean value can come from anywhere; there is nothing special about ISNUMBER().

Sometimes a user would prefer to report these numeric values instead of the Booleans, and sometimes some more complex formulas actually need the numeric equivalents to work properly.

This technique is very common in Excel formulas.

You'll see it used often in array formulas where it can turn an entire array of Booleans into an array of 1s and 0s as succinctly as it was used here.

The equal sign at the very beginning is how all formulas should be started.

The formula in your question is not a good example of how to use this technique however. There would never be a reason to use it when IFERROR() is set to return a zero length string. Removing the IFERROR() function from the formula would set it straight.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer!